# Invalid cookie header error in WAS Liberty using openidConnectClient feature

Tags: java, websphere-liberty

Hi I am trying to use openidConnectClient feature in WAS Liberty server. The SSO redirect happens good but after authentication I get below error in my WAS log.

```
[WARNING ] Invalid cookie header: "Set-Cookie: bm_sz=E6857FC73F8747AB2F75A793B7D65133~YAAQDSMzuIh7CVtvAQAA4aDhtAZIt/4HtgRF9vJI0bzlLI1nndWBD+73K2ut9qe/cqrPHNtmvr9+f/knnsbRz+Ecsc4OtOmry6EdumGHqfyc3A6MM7tRHVtyu6juFPixoH+uCbj4gPzHxnjY9dmIc0iys4FAR7+HDFMZ0eVovgmrGKjfLrB/1a; Domain=.ibm.com; Path=/; Expires=Fri, 17 Jan 2020 23:01:23 GMT; Max-Age=14400; HttpOnly". Invalid 'expires' attribute: Fri, 17 Jan 2020 23:01:23 GMT
[WARNING ] Invalid cookie header: "Set-Cookie: _abck=C18B3D490F8A66E4FB164ACC795BDBE3~-1~YAAQDSMzuIl7CVtvAQAA4aDhtAP6sYDTSY3APsHdSQ5+1dv3bxrSDVeL86hSbZ846hnQ/PG68/ikeHSfmrt8FBq9Ujg9J+4fk5RLRgWelESCkckJA9JMfvY4RArNMk9j5bKClfXuUZ8ajxZs22pzNips6kfh+87M8BhIRisRkpsCKqaSg9FLvdijhTKtLkj/dwTPtQfVSKCwBKfYOFUkUW+Hx/4/UQh2flAXIK/tJLzezGbBvBMDtOhqzyZnPmn9ofgz+i1Ttj9HSi3bAQr+NlvbvjG0791qUFWQTLZPC42Pk2x3ZJot~-1~-1~-1; Domain=.ibm.com; Path=/; Expires=Sat, 16 Jan 2021 19:01:23 GMT; Max-Age=31536000; Secure". Invalid 'expires' attribute: Sat, 16 Jan 2021 19:01:23 GMT
```

I have below features enable in server.xml

```
<featureManager>
        <feature>jsp-2.3</feature>
        <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
        <feature>jdbc-4.2</feature>
        <feature>servlet-4.0</feature>
        <feature>transportSecurity-1.0</feature>
        <feature>jndi-1.0</feature>
        <feature>openidConnectClient-1.0</feature>
        <feature>appSecurity-2.0</feature>
        <feature>sessionDatabase-1.0</feature>
    </featureManager>
```

WAS liberty version and  Java version mentioned below

```
Product name: WebSphere Application Server
Product version: 19.0.0.12
Product edition: BASE_ILAN

-----
java version "1.8.0_221"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 8.0.5.40 - pwa6480sr5fp40-20190807_01(SR5 FP40))
IBM J9 VM (build 2.9, JRE 1.8.0 Windows 10 amd64-64-Bit Compressed References 20190802_424001 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
OpenJ9   - 106f6ce
OMR      - fe07f6f
IBM      - af2a365)
JCL - 20190712_01 based on Oracle jdk8u221-b11
```

Answer (score 0):

I think something other than Liberty is setting those cookies, maybe the OIDC provider Liberty is talking to, or something else along the communication path. The Apache httpcomponents class that Liberty uses doesn't like the expires attribute, so logs that warning.  It's found in org/apache/http/client/protocol/ResponseProcessCookies.class.  Since these cookies aren't used by the OIDC client, I think you can probably ignore this warning.  You -might- be able to suppress it by setting the trace specification to include org.apache.http.client.protocol.*=off

Comment: Thanks for reply Bruce. I am using IBMID as OIDC provider. which setting file I should put this org.apache.http.client.protocol.*=off  in was libery ?

Comment: It would go in the oidc client's server.xml like this: 
<logging  traceSpecification="*=info:org.apache.http.client.protocol.*=off"/>

Comment: I get same error
 
 <openidConnectClient
  authorizationEndpointUrl="${sso.auth.url}" clientId="${sso.clientID}"
  clientSecret="${sso.clientSecret}" httpsRequired="true" id="blueid"
  issuerIdentifier="${sso.identifier}" mapIdentityToRegistryUser="false"
  redirectToRPHostAndPort="${sso.redirect}" scope="openid"
                signatureAlgorithm="RS256" tokenEndpointUrl="${sso.token.url}"
  trustAliasName="idaasKey" trustStoreRef="defaultKeyStore"
 uniqueUserIdentifier="preferred_username"
  userIdentityToCreateSubject="preferred_username">
 </openidConnectClient>

Comment: <logging traceSpecification="*=info:org.apache.http.client.protocol.*=off"/>

Comment: A code change has been made, these warnings should go away in  20.002